# Probability formula derivation

Tags: pr.probability

How is the following formula derived which yields the probability that the sum of the squares of n random draws from the closed interval [-1,1] is less than one?

formula: (1/2^n)*pi^(n/2)/(n/2)!

Comment: I suspect Stirling's formula is involved, since $\pi$ and factorials appear.  But I also suspect this is closer to being an exercise than a research question, especially since you seem sure of the formula.  So this question might be more appropriate for stackexchange or maybe Wikipedia's mathematics reference desk than for mathoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Volume of the ball divided by volume of the cube.